# Elastic search query on two values - term and range?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to do a query where I want documents based on two values - name (string) and percentage (number).
Example would be - I want those documents which have "audience.location.countries.name" = "US" and "audience.location.countries.percentage" > 60. So I want a document which has an object {"name":"US", "percentage":"65"}
Here, "audience.location.countries" is a an array of objects with two properties - {"name","percentage"}. 
Here is an example document:

```
"location": {
              "countries": [
                {
                  "name": "CA",
                  "percentage": 4
                },
                {
                  "name": "GB",
                  "percentage": 5
                },
                {
                  "name": "JP",
                  "percentage": 8
                },
                {
                  "name": "US",
                  "percentage": 60
                }
              ]}
```

This a query that I tried but it throws an error: "[and] query malformed, no start_object after query name"

```
GET opensponsorship/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "isPublic": true
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "isDeleted": false
              }
            },
            {
              "and":[
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "audience.location.countries.name": "US"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term":{
                      "audience.location.countries.percentage": {"gt": 59}
                    }
                  }
                ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "size": "60",
      "from": 0,
      "sort": [
        {
          "followers": {
            "order": "desc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am new to elastic search and have a very limited knowledge. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell the query is "broken" on several accounts:

1. You use the [deprecated `and` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/query-dsl-and-query.html) (BTW, what ES version are you using?)
2. The `range` and `term` filters over the `name` and `percentage` fields are mixed
3. The field `audience.location.countries` should be a "[nested object](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)"

Following is a query which resolves issues 1 & 2. I'll then explain issue 3:

```
GET opensponsorship/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "isPublic": true
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "isDeleted": false
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "audience.location.countries.name": "US"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "audience.location.countries.percentage": {
              "gt": 59
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": "60",
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "followers": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Regarding issue 3, I suggest you read up on [nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in elasticsearch. 
In short - If `audience.location.countries` is not a nested object, you will have "false positive" results due to how Elastic "flattens" objects. 
To fix this you'll need to 1) make `audience.location.countries` a nested object type in the mapping, and 2) wrap the `contries` term filters with a nested query in the following manner:

```
GET opensponsorship/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "isPublic": true
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "isDeleted": false
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "audience.location.countries",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "audience.location.countries.name": "US"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "audience.location.countries.percentage": {
                        "gt": 59
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": "60",
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "followers": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!